# Private flight to Canada from UK - visa or eTA?

Tags: visas, canada, eta

Does an eTA apply for private flights to Canada from the UK? (Via Greenland).

Comment: [visa-exempt foreign nationals who fly to, or transit through a Canadian airport, need an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA)](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta.asp). Seems clear to me.

Comment: The reason I ask is it always makes reference to scheduled flights with travelling by air - but this is incorrect for a private flight. For example an ESTA to the US is valid for scheduled flights but not private - something only cleared up in smallprint.

Answer (score 3):

The [Entry requirements by country](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-all.asp) page has this to say

> The following travellers need an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA) to board their flight to Canada. However, these travellers do not need an eTA if entering by land or sea.

It doesn't make a distinction between scheduled or chartered flights.

If you go to the [visa tool](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) and enter your country, you will see this:

> Fly to or transit through a Canadian airport:
>
> You need to apply online for an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA).

depending on your nationality and again nothing else. Same on the [eTA](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta.asp) page

> visa-exempt foreign nationals who fly to, or transit through a Canadian airport, need an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA)

This is quite clear in my opinion.

Finally, common sense applies: can you imagine the outrage if people rich enough to charter a plane were exempted? Osama bin Laden was estimated to have a net worth of $50 million. Also, what about tour operators who charter a plane for a group of people...? The loopholes would be unending.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My main hestiation in taking it as any flight is that the US ESTA is very similarly worded but if you go hunting, you find private flights actually require VISAs. As for the common sense, I wasn't suggesting that you don't need any form of checking if you are able to fly private but that you need a Visa as opposed to an eTA.

Comment: I am completely put of ideas as to where else would you hunt, I linked three different pages.